# Apt on WSL2's version of Ubuntu doesn't include latest version of ruby-build

Tags: apt, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, ruby-build

I installed WSL2 and Ubuntu 20.04, which includes Ruby 2.7.0:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I would like to install Ruby 3.0.1, but `ruby-build` doesn't have it:

```
...
2.4.0-rc1
2.4.0
2.4.1
2.5.0-dev
jruby-1.5.6
jruby-1.6.3
...
```

I updated `apt`:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:3 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:5 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release [815 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [982 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [774 kB]
Fetched 1971 kB in 1s (1379 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

But the version of `ruby-build` is still old:

```
$ apt show ruby-build
Package: ruby-build
Version: 20170726-1
Priority: optional
...
```

My OSX machine:

```
$ ruby-build --version
ruby-build 20210510
```

Is this an issue w/ Ubuntu, `apt`, or something else?  How do I fix it?

Comment: This is expected. The version you have is the latest available from the official repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu releases are either "long-term support" (LTS) or "interim releases" (see [Ubuntu Release Cycle](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle)).  The "even-year, April/Spring" (e.g. 20.04 or 22.04) release is the long-term support release, which is designed to have stable, proven software packages that will be supported by Canonical for 5 years.  The other 3 interim releases between those (e.g. 20.10, 21.04, 21.10) *may* update packages to newer releases for testing.

That said, Canonical only puts LTS releases of Ubuntu in the Microsoft Store for WSL.  It's [possible to upgrade](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/installing-ubuntu-20-10-on-wsl/18941) to an interim release.  Just be aware that you are on a "less stable" version.  You may want to do this in a separate installation and still keep your 20.04 version around.  If so, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067679/11810933) for my write-up on how to do this.  There's still no guarantee that 21.04 includes a later ruby-build.  It obviously wouldn't have the May 10th release.  I haven't checked the package list to see what ruby-build version is in 21.04.

Anyway, I'd propose a different alternative.  You mention that your MacOS version is the latest, and I'm assuming you installed it with Homebrew (`brew`).  The ruby-build maintainers are the ones who update that package and make sure the latest is available through Homebrew.  If you want to install and use Homebrew on WSL, you [can as well](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux).  I haven't done this myself, but it seems entirely possible from the Homebrew doc.  I think I'd purge the ruby-build package you installed from the Ubuntu repositories first, though, to avoid conflicts.