# WSL2 doesn't work after using su to change user

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL2 with the *Remote - WSL* extension for Visual Studio Code.
If I do `code .`, Visual Code opens in the specified folder.  However, if I change user with `su`, the same command outputs:

```
Command 'code' not found, did you mean:
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be running into [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/286), where the Remote extension always uses the default user.

While no solution here is ideal, there are (at least) three options, depending on your exact use-case:

- Temporarily change the default user:

  You'll need to `sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf` and add:

  ```
  [user]
  default=other_username
  ```

  Then `wsl --terminate <distro>` (from PowerShell, CMD, or the Start menu), then restart.
- [Use two different WSL instances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067679/11810933) with different default users in each one.
- Possibly, give your default user permissions to whatever files you are trying to edit for the other user.