# "Code" command not working, on different user in ubuntu wsl

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, vscode-remote

So, I have 2 users in my Ubuntu WSL, and if I try to run `code .`, when the wsl opens in the main user as default it works fine, but when I switch to second user using `su second_user`, then running `code .` gives the following error:-

```
Command 'code' not found, did you mean:
  command 'tcode' from deb emboss (6.6.0+dfsg-11ubuntu1)
  command 'ode' from deb plotutils (2.6-11)
  command 'cde' from deb cde (0.1+git9-g551e54d-1.2)
  command 'node' from deb nodejs (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3)
  command 'cdde' from deb cdde (0.3.1-1build1)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Then, if I go back to my previous user, then it stops working there as well, and gives the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSL2 after su the command code . doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550829/wsl2-after-su-the-command-code-doesnt-work).  Essentially [any method](https://superuser.com/q/1566022/1210833) of changing the default user will work, so if you'd like, you can add your (slightly different) solution to that question.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Sorry for the duplicate question, didn't find it. Thanks

Comment: No worries!  Duplicates can be tough to find sometimes.  I only knew it was there because I had answered it! ;-).  I've edited the original one to hopefully make it a bit easier to find in the future, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a fix that I found for my situation was to change the default user of the WSL, by entering the following command in PowerShell of windows.

```
ubuntu config --default-user second_user
```

Where the general syntax of the command will be:-

```
<distro_name> config --default-user <username>
```